# Setting a List to include 2 TextViews

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a list adapter that holds a TextView and an ImageView. I can set the image and the text fro each item on the list. The variable for TextView is tvFullName.

Can I have tvFullName to set an item in the list to a text and have tvFullNameOne
also set the item in the list to a text?
Like two variables which each create items in the list with text?

This is my layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center|left"
        android:padding="5dp" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ivImage"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:src="@drawable/profile" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvFullName"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Adapter........

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.relationship_inflater, null);
        Holder holder = new Holder();
        //connectOrDisconnectUser();
        holder.ivPhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
        holder.tvFullName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFullName);
        holder.tvFullName.setText(usersInfo.get(position).get(
                Relationship.TAG_USERNAME));
        imageLoader.DisplayImage(
                usersInfo.get(position).get(Relationship.TAG_PROFILE_PICTURE),
                holder.ivPhoto);
        return view;
    }
```

Comment: Yes you can. just create the Text View. add it to the Cell Class.. and populate it the same way you did `tvFullName`. It would be like adding the same  `tvFullName` but with a different Name...

Comment: Can u show me a specific example

Comment: show me how>>>>>>

Comment: Plus I want to have each item have each their own onclick value.

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Using-an-ArrayAdapter-with-ListView#using-a-custom-arrayadapter

Comment: You have not stated if you are using ListView or RecyclerView. Please show your Adapter code

Comment: ListView........

Comment: I posted the adapter

Comment: I don't understand the question... Your XML clearly has only one TextView. The code uses two

Comment: sorry changed it..

Comment: Okay, so you tried something, it seems... What was wrong with that approach? What errors did you have?

Comment: What I tried made the two items I set as the same ListView therefore had the same onClick value.

Answer (score 0):

> What I tried made the two items I set as the same ListView therefore had the same onClick value

If you want the click events on the view elements within the list, you can use individual listeners.

For example, with your current code

```
holder.ivPhoto = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.ivImage);
// holder.ivPhoto.setOnClickListener();
holder.tvFullName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFullName);
// holder.tvFullName.setOnClickListener();
```

Or you can check which view was clicked in the item listener set on the listview

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    long viewId = view.getId();

    switch(viewId) {
        case R.id.ivImage:
          Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Image clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
          break;
        case R.id.tvFullName:
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Full name clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

As for your question, yes, of course you can add whatever extra text you want.